# Difference between ./ and / in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, path

I have been using Linux awhile and one thing I have never have understood, particularly when using the `find` command, is the difference between `./` and `/`. Usually I only use this format when using the `find` command. For some reason this makes a big difference, especially when searching by file name on lets say the entire root.

Example:

```
sudo find ./ -size +10M
sudo find / -size +10M

sudo find ./ -iname "zebra.txt"
sudo find / -iname "zebra.txt"
```

Comment: `find .` or `find ./` starts the search from the current working directory. `find /` starts from the root of the filesystem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Questions about Linux and its utilities should be posted to [unix.se] or [su] instead.

Answer (score 1):

`./` means the current directory, wherever you've `cd`-ed to.
For example if I run the find command in `Desktop` with `./`, it means to find files and folders in `Desktop`.

Sometimes `./` is used to run executables. Like this:

```
./run.sh
```

But `/` means root partition.
For example some peoples kidding new person with very dangerous command. **Do not run this command because your root partition will be destroyed and all of the OS files and folders will be removed.**

```
sudo rm -rf /
```

Comment: Why post a dangerous command? There are a thousand other examples you could use that wouldn't need a bolded disclaimer.